# How to use grep to match a string with spaces in it?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, awk

Can anyone help me with this:

I am trying to extract a time stamp, by matching a string. For this am using combination of grep/awk commands. As the sting has 4 spces before [1] and one after, am confused how to work around it. Am new to programming, so need some help here.

```
IS="$(grep 'Starting    [1] TaskInit' process.log |  awk '{print $4}')"
echo "$IS"
```

Aim: It should match the string in the process.log file and should print out the time stamp related to that row.

Comment: If you surround the pattern with `'`, spaces should not be any problem. What’s your expected result and what are you getting instead? Have you tried to break your command down and debug its parts?

Comment: I have surrounded it with ', when am trying to print the output its giving me nothing. If I keep only TaskInit as part of the string, its printing the time. But, there are many TaskInit's in the log file. That is why I want to extract the value from the above string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spaces are not the problem here, it should work fine.
But the brackets `[` need to be escaped in regex. So write:

```
grep 'Starting    \[1] TaskInit' process.log
```

In your case, as you want to match a fixed string and not a regex, you should use `grep -F` instead. Then you don't need to escape:

```
grep -F 'Starting    [1] TaskInit' process.log
```

Comment: The second format worked here for me. The first one is giving nothing in return.

Comment: There is a typo in the first format: the closing bracket should also be quoted: `\[1\]` in place of `\[1]`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to escape the square brackets, because they have special meaning:

```
grep 'Starting    \[1\] TaskInit' process.log
```

In addition I would use only `awk` for this task, for this purpose you need something like:

```
awk '/Starting    \[1] TaskInit/ {print $4}' process.log
```

Comment: the closing bracket does not need to be escaped.

Comment: +1 for `awk` only solution.